# How do I print every element after the first, twice?

Tags: python, list

The usage case would be for dates.... for example:

```
Monday, Tuesday
Tuesday, Wednesday
Wednesday, Thursday
Thursday, Friday.
```

Or using numerics:

```
0, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
5, 6
```

If I have a list of numbers like
`numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, I've tried:

```
for x, y in zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2]):
    print(x, y)
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: "Friday" or "6" aren't repeated twice. Is that desirable?

Comment: @enke yes, that's fine. essentially if my list was only up until friday I would expect the pairwise iteration to stop there.

Comment: cool. please consider accepting the given answer since it answers your question

Comment: @enke yep, just had to wait a few more minutes before it would let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for x, y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    print(x, y)

# 0 1
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 4
# 4 5
# 5 6
```

From python 3.10, you can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) instead.

Comment: agh! I knew there was proper terminology for the method but I couldn't find it for the life of me. Thank you.